# SectionList throws Warning that is only for FlatList when using flexWrap

Tags: react-native

SectionList throws Warning that is only for FlatList when using flexWrap

```
<SectionList
sections={DATA}
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
renderItem={renderItems}
contentContainerStyle={styles.sectionStyle}
renderSectionHeader={renderHeader}
/>
```

This is the style I've be using coz i need to show the images in a grid format with respective headers

```
 sectionStyle: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        paddingBottom: 100
    },
```

Exact thing I wanted is like this

[Image Example](https://google.com/photos/static/2020/images/index/devices_mobile.jpg)

where june 2 is the list header and images are children

Comment: What is your purpose of flexWrap?

Comment: I have list of images for each section header and I need to show all the elements in a grid style so when the children overflows I use it to wrap the contents within header

Comment: @VuPhung this is an example where June 2 is the header and children are images https://www.google.com/photos/static/2020/images/index/devices_mobile.jpg